# Is there a way to control the number of threads that are active at any point in time in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am running load test with jmeter with selenium webdriver sample. Purpose is to load test and understand amount of time taken by 500 users to complete a survey on a web dash board. When executing i need to control the number of concurrent threads, and it should be more than 10. New thread should be spawned if number of concurrent threads becomes less that 10.
How do i achieve this. Any pointer in this direction will be helpful.

Regards,
Seshan K.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-4-stepping-thread-group-and-concurrency-thread) you can set the amount of threads in the Stepping Thread Group. This might be great to read through.

Answer (score 0):

You must be looking for the [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/)

> This thread group offers simplified approach for configuring threads schedule. **It is intended to maintain the level of concurrency, which means starting additional during the runtime threads if there's not enough of them running in parallel.**

So it is just enough to install the Concurrency Thread Group using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) and use it instead of normal JMeter's [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

[image: JMeter Concurrency Thread Group]

Comment: Can u pls have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58066367/jmeter-multiple-concurrent-users-in-single-thread-group